# Vector of shared pointers to templated classes

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a templated class `TaskRunner` that takes a polymorphic type `Task` and I want to create a container of shared pointers to them.

```
class Task {
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class LoudTask : Task {
    void run() {
        std::cout << "RUNNING!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class QuietTask : Task {
    void run() {
        std::cout << "running!" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T> class TaskRunner {
    public:
        TaskRunner<T>() {
            task = std::make_unique<T>();
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<T> task;
};


using Runner = std::shared_ptr<TaskRunner<Task>>;
```

However I get `error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'` with:

```
std::vector<Runner> runners;

runners.push_back(std::make_shared<TaskRunner<QuietTask>>());
runners.push_back(std::make_shared<TaskRunner<LoudTask>>());
```

Due to:

> note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'shared_ptr<TaskRunner>' to 'const shared_ptr<TaskRunner>' for 1st argument

Comment: `TaskRunner<LoudTask>` and `TaskRunner<Task>` are unrelated classes, having no more in common than say `int` and `std::string`. You could derive `TaskRunner<T>` from a non-template polymorphic base class e.g. `TaskRunnerBase`, and store pointers to that.

Comment: `TaskRunner<QuietTask>` is not  a subtype of `TaskRunner<Task>`, even if `QuietTask` is a subtype of `Task`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I still get `no known conversion from 'shared_ptr<TaskRunner<LoudTask>>' to 'const shared_ptr<TaskRunnerBase>'`?

Comment: Does `TaskRunner` need to be a template? Seems to defeat the object of `Task` being polymorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented IgorTandetnik's suggestion, and it works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Task {
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class LoudTask : Task {
public:
    void run() {
        std::cout << "RUNNING!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class QuietTask : Task {
public:
    void run() {
        std::cout << "running!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class TaskRunnerBase
{
public:
    virtual void run() =0;
};

template <class T>
class TaskRunner: public TaskRunnerBase {
    public:
        TaskRunner():
            task(std::make_unique<T>()) {
        }
        void run() override
        {
            task->run();
        }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<T> task;
};

int main()
{
    using Runner = std::shared_ptr<TaskRunnerBase>;
    std::vector<Runner> runners;
    
    runners.push_back(std::make_shared<TaskRunner<QuietTask>>());
    runners.push_back(std::make_shared<TaskRunner<LoudTask>>());

    runners[0]->run();
    runners[1]->run();
}
```

Output:

```
running!
RUNNING!
```

Note however that TaskRunner doesn't need to be a template; as it is currently implemented above, it has a kind of double role: (1) task factory, and (2) container and runner of tasks.

[paolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71818739/671366) separates this out nicely, there, the factory aspect is moved to the main function.

Answer (score 2):

If `TaskRunner` is supposed to run tasks that inherit from `Task` only, you may consider de-templatizing it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Task {
   public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class LoudTask : public Task {
   public:
    void run() override { std::cout << "RUNNING!" << std::endl; }
};

class QuietTask : public Task {
   public:
    void run() override { std::cout << "running!" << std::endl; }
};

class TaskRunner {
   public:
    explicit TaskRunner(std::unique_ptr<Task>&& task_)
        : task(std::move(task_)) {}

    void run() {
        if (this->task) this->task->run();
    }

   private:
    std::unique_ptr<Task> task;
};

int main() {
    using Runner = std::shared_ptr<TaskRunner>;
    std::vector<Runner> runners;

    runners.push_back(
        std::make_shared<TaskRunner>(std::make_unique<QuietTask>()));
    runners.push_back(
        std::make_shared<TaskRunner>(std::make_unique<LoudTask>()));

    for (auto& runner : runners) runner->run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another implementation that eliminates the need for another inheritance hierarchy and vtable since we already accomplished that with the Task hierarchy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Task {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class LoudTask : public Task {
public:
    void run() {
        std::cout << "RUNNING!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class QuietTask : public Task {
public:
    void run() {
        std::cout << "running!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class TaskRunner {
public:
    TaskRunner(std::unique_ptr<LoudTask> task) : m_task{ std::unique_ptr<Task>(task.release()) } {}
    TaskRunner(std::unique_ptr<QuietTask> task) : m_task{ std::unique_ptr<Task>(task.release()) } {}
    void run()
    {
        m_task->run();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Task> m_task;
};

using Runner = std::shared_ptr<TaskRunner>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Runner> runners;

    runners.push_back(std::make_shared<TaskRunner>(std::make_unique<QuietTask>()));
    runners.push_back(std::make_shared<TaskRunner>(std::make_unique<LoudTask>()));

    runners[0]->run();
    runners[1]->run();
}
```